# OkHttp Cancel a Request if a client fails to respond within certain amount of time

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using OkHttp client in my Java Application and I am calling one of my client, but for some issue, it is creating a bottleneck because client's service is slow and my requests are getting queued up. So is there a way to cancel a request if the client does not respond within a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

You could create OkHttp client builder setting time out values something like this below.

```
     final OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = 
     getHttpClientBuilder(RetrofitLogger.Level.BODY);
     Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
     builder.baseUrl(<BASE URL>);
     builder.client(clientBuilder.build());



     public Builder getHttpClientBuilder() {
        final Builder builder = new Builder();
          if (shortTimeout) {
            builder.readTimeout(SHORT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            builder.connectTimeout(SHORT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(false);
           }
        else {
          builder.readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           builder.connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        builder.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(IDLE_CONNECTIONS, IDLE_TIMEOUT, 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        return builder;
      }
```

Comment: This is Connection Timeout. But in My case the call is taking time i.e the client method that I am calling is taking time to execute, not the connection. I have tried this though. Thanks for your answer.